# How to determine negative values of arc functions?

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone explain me how do they work? I memorized the table of values for sin/cos/tan/cot and radian-degreee values. 
But, how come, when it is $\arcsin -1/2$ this is $-\pi/6$. So the same thing as $\arcsin 1/2$ just with a different sign. Why it is not $5\pi/6$?  But when it is $\arccos -\sqrt{2}/2$ it is $3\pi/4$, not a $\pi/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arcsine function is defined as the inverse function of sin function but
you should take into account the domain and the range of each. The domain of
sin is $\left[ -\frac{\pi }{2},\ \frac{\pi }{2}\right] $ and its range is $%
\left[ -1,\ 1\right] $ so the arcsine domain is $\left[ -1,1\right] $ and
its range is $\left[ -\frac{\pi }{2},\ \frac{\pi }{2}\right] .$ So if you
look for $\arcsin \frac{-1}{2}$ the answer should be $\frac{-\pi }{6}$ (Note
that $\frac{5\pi }{6}=2.618$ is not in the range of arcsine function. Note
that sin function is bijective from $\left[ -\frac{\pi }{2},\ \frac{\pi }{2}%
\right] $ onto $\left[ -1,\ 1\right] .$ If you enlarge the domain to
something greater than $\left[ -\frac{\pi }{2},\ \frac{\pi }{2}\right] $ the
sin function wouldn't be one-to-one. (it remains onto but not one-to-one,
not injective)

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Consider $sin(-x)=-sin(x)$ and $cos(-x)=cos(x)$ for all real $x$.

The arcsin is usually defined as the inverse of the sine function in the
interval [$-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}$], hence the negative values.

Answer (score 1):

**Another hint:**

Make a sketch with the trigonometric circle. You'll see at once $\,\sin\frac{5\pi}6>0\,$  and $\,\cos\frac{3\pi}4<0$.

Answer (score 1):

A very good and concise answer is already given by Idris but I want to give you a brief theory about them.

$\sin{^-1}$, $cos^{-1}$... $\cot^{-1}$ are actually relations unless we provide Domain and Range for them.

We say them relations because *A relation is one that can create more than one output for a single input and a function can not have two or more outputs for a single input*.

When we say that $\cos^{-1}{\frac{1}{2}}$, we are saying that *find the angles whose cosine is $\frac{1}{2}$*. There are infinitely many angles whose cosine is $\frac{1}{2}$ but since we want them as *Functions*, we restrict their domain and range and so in the *range* the output is $\frac{\pi}{3}$

The angle (output) we get from these inverse functions is called **Principle angle** and their notation is slightly changed i.e. we write the first letter with capital.

For instance,

$Cos^{-1}$, $Sin^{-1}$...$Cot^{-1}$.